# Simpler expression for $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k!}$

Tags: factorial

Is there a way to express $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k!}$$ in a simpler way that doesn't use sums up to n ?

I've searched for this around the web and found that the subfactorial function can help with this, however, it's also defined by a sum, so this does not meet the criteria.

Comment: Try to have a look here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialSums.html

Comment: For all *practical* purposes, your sum is *approximately* equal to its last term.

Answer (score 0):

If you plug it in wolfram Alpha, you get an alternate expression without the subfactorial, but it has the gamma function which by definition is still a sum (integral).

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=summation+from+1+to+n+of++k+factorial+

Comment: It lacks the summation, but is hardly simpler than the given formula.